# Using Sidekiq, Capistrano,Sinatra for deploys

Tags: ruby, sinatra, capistrano, sidekiq

As part of a capistrano deploy with Sinatra:

```
* executing `sidekiq:start'
* executing "cd /var/www/nodes/current ; nohup bundle exec sidekiq -e production -C /var/www/nodes/current/config/sidekiq.yml -P /var/www/nodes/current/tmp/pids/sidekiq.pid -r /var/www/nodes/current/app/nodes.rb >> /var/www/nodes/current/log/sidekiq.log 2>&1 &"
```

I cannot see anyway to get the -r (require) to point to my Sinatra as per [sidekiq/issues/10](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/10) . The app lives in ./app/nodes.rb.

my config.ru is

```
require './app/nodes'
run Nodes 
map '/sidekiq' do
    run Sidekiq::Web
end
```

'./app/nodes' loads in all the environment both nodes and sidekiq needs to run.

In [sidekiq/capistrano.rb](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/master/lib/sidekiq/capistrano.rb) there is currently no option to pass in an -r flag.

sidekiq.log reports this error, as expected:

```
2012-10-12T01:04:59Z 8175 TID-bf65s INFO:                  
2012-10-12T01:04:59Z 8175 TID-bf65s INFO:   Please point sidekiq to a Rails 3 application or a Ruby file
2012-10-12T01:04:59Z 8175 TID-bf65s INFO:   to load your worker classes with -r [DIR|FILE].
2012-10-12T01:04:59Z 8175 TID-bf65s INFO:
```

Any ideas?

V

Answer (score 2):

Resolved by Mike Perham, creator of Sidekiq: [on github](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/440). In the sidekiq.yml, you can add a specific require option. Thanks very much!